# A new column taken number from previous columns plus special character between number

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with numbers and I would like to create a new column in the same dataframe with the values of the first column plus ':' plus the values of the second column.

```
data = {'First Column Name':  ['1', '2'],
        'Second Column Name': ['555', '666'] 
        
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['First Column Name','Second Column Name'])

print (df)

  First Column Name Second Column Name
0                 1                555
1                 2                666
```

The desire column I need should be like this

```
Desire column
0         1:555
1         2:666
```

The value of the first column can be numbers or the character X or Y.
The value of the second column are only number from de 1 to 9999999999

Answer (score 3):

Use [str.cat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
df['Desire column'] = df['First Column Name'].str.cat(df['Second Column Name'], sep=':')
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  First Column Name Second Column Name Desire column
0                 1                555         1:555
1                 2                666         2:666
```

As an alternative:

```
df['Desire column'] = df['First Column Name'] + ':'  + df['Second Column Name']
```

If the columns are of type numeric, convert them first using [astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['Desire column'] = df['First Column Name'].astype(str) + ':' + df['Second Column Name'].astype(str)
```

The same applies for *cat*. Note the if you are using pandas 1.0+ the recommended way is to do:

```
df['Desire column'] = df['First Column Name'].astype('string') + ':' + df['Second Column Name'].astype('string')
```

This means the *dtype* is going to be [StringDtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.StringDtype.html#pandas.StringDtype). To understand why this is recommended and, to learn a few tricks with working with text, read the [user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can very simply do this:

```
df['desired_column'] = df['First Column Name'].astype(str) + ':' + df['Second Column Name'].astype(str)
```

which prints:

```
   First Column Name  Second Column Name desired_column
0                  1                 555          1:555
1                  2                 666          2:666
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `appy` `join` along columns:

```
df['col_3'] = df.apply(':'.join, 1)
```

Output:

```
  col_1 col_2  col_3
0     1   555  1:555
1     2   666  2:666
```